# Двумерный QVector: Как правильно объявить и инициализировать?

Tags: c++, qt, vector

Пишу игру "Жизнь". Возник такой вопрос.
Имеется, допустим, класс LifeMatrix, в котором будет двумерный, динамический(не знаю, подойдет ли динамический) вектор, чтобы я мог проводить некие действия в этом же классе(допустим, подсчитать соседей у определенной клетки)

Объявил его так в заголовочном файле:

```
QVector<QVector<bool> *> *m_matrix;
```

Инициализировал я его так:

```
LifeMatrix::LifeMatrix(short horizontalCount, short verticalCount, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    //
    m_matrix    = new QVector<QVector<bool> *>(verticalCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < verticalCount; i++)
        m_matrix[i] = new QVector<bool>(horizontalCount);
```

Честно говоря, я не знаю, правильно ли я это сделал.
Ибо когда я захотел заполнить его некими данными:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_matrix->count(); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m_matrix[i].count(); i++)
        m_matrix[i][j] = false;
```

Показано несколько ошибок:

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QVector<QVector<bool>*>' and 'QVector<bool>*')
         m_matrix[i] = new QVector<bool>(horizontalCount);
                     ^
```

и вот тут. Но это вообще что-то странное, ибо я как-бы уже могу закидывать данные. Не так ли?

```
ошибка: cannot convert 'bool' to 'QVector<bool>*' in assignment
             m_matrix[i][j] = false;
                            ^
```

У меня возник такой вопрос. Почему-то у меня ещё ругается на `m_matrix[i].count()`, когда я меняю точку на `->`. Ведь вектор хранит указатели. Если оставить точку, то ошибка пропадает.

```
 ошибка: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'QVector<QVector<bool>*>'
             for (int j = 0; j < m_matrix[i]->count(); i++)
                                            ^
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае я использовал бы не вектор, а обычный двухмерный массив. Вектора хороши, когда количество элементов постоянно меняется в процессе работы программы, у вас же, насколько я понял, размер поля задается один раз, и дальше используется.

```
class LifeMatrix
{
public:
    LifeMatrix() {
        m_matrix = nullptr;
        m_nx = 0;
        m_ny = 0;
    }

    void allocate(int nx, int ny) {
        m_nx = nx;
        m_ny = ny;
        m_matrix = new bool *[nx];
        for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
        {
            m_matrix[i] = new bool[ny];
        }
    }

    void freeMemory() {
        if (m_matrix == nullptr)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_nx; i++)
            delete [] m_matrix[i];
        delete [] m_matrix;
        m_matrix = nullptr;
    }

protected:
    int m_nx;
    int m_ny;
    bool **m_matrix;
};
```

Понадобится еще определить функции доступа к количеству ячеек по x и y и сеттер/геттер для жизни в ячейке чтобы все было по феншую.

Comment: Ну как-бы я планировал, что размер поля должен меняться. Массив - это хорошо и довольно безопасно(если хорошо сделать) и не нагружено, но всё таки придется менять размер поля. Я так понимаю, что, если используются обычные двухмерные массивы, то при изменении поля придется delete всё дело и заново выделять память?

Comment: Планируется менять размер поля прямо в процессе игры? Или под сменой размера подразумевается остановка игры и перезапуск с другим размером? Во втором случае достаточно вызвать уже написанный мной метод `freeMemory` и затем `allocate` с нужными новыми размерами.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужна двумерная матрица - просто используйте двумерную матрицу, существует множество их реализаций, в том числе header-only. Как вариант, можно взять реализацию из boost. Если хотите реализовать самостоятельно, лучше реализуйте примерно так:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix{
  std::vector<T> data_;
  std::size_t size1_; //количество строк
  std::size_t size2_; //количество столбцов
public:
  Matrix(std::size_t size1, std::size_t size2): 
    data_(size1*size2), 
    size1_(size1), 
    size2_(size2)
  {  }

  std::size_t size1() const {return size1_;}
  std::size_t size2() const {return size2_;}

  T& operator()(std::size_t i1, std::size_t i2){
    assert(i1 < size1 && i2 < size2);
    return data_[i2 + i1*size2()];
  }
  const T& operator()(std::size_t i1, std::size_t i2) const {
    assert(i1 < size1 && i2 < size2);
    return data_[i2 + i1*size2()];
  }
};
```

Вектор на вектор хранить смысла нет, да и работать с такой конструкцией на самом деле не очень удобно. QVector тоже можно использовать, но у него при обращении по индексу будет лишнее косвенное обращение (он хранит данные через двойной указатель по некоторым причинам). Изменение размера можно сделать путём создания новой матрицы и копирования (перемещения) в неё содержимого старой. Matrix из boost умеет выделять память заранее, позволяя свободно менять размер в некотором диапазоне  и выделять память при необходимости, но вручную это реализовывать особого смысла нет.

Если вам нужен именно вектор векторов со строками разной длины, тогда лучше использовать `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, тут уже разница с QVector будет в два косвенных обращения. Возможно, это не критично для вас, но я не вижу смысла в снижении производительности без нужды (впрочем, как и в обратном).

Comment: Отлично расписано, спасибо. Буду делать через двумерный массив

Answer (score 0):

Вы работаете не с векторами, а с указателями на вектора. Как следствие, например `operator[]` не определен для `QVector<T> *`, он определен для `QVector<T>`.

Сделайте `m_matrix` просто вектором векторов: `QVector<QVector<bool> >`.

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне задать размер вектора? Через resize()? Говорят, плохая идея. тем более, когда вектор из векторов

Comment: Так это динамический массив, ему не нужно задавать. Можно заранее выделить память на n элементов с помощью `reserve`.

Comment: То есть я в конструкторе могу просто сделать так: `m_matrix.reserve(verticalCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < m_matrix.count(); i++)
        m_matrix[i].reserve(horizontalCount);` ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @arrowd Что же вы советуете! Не `reserve` надо делать, а именно `resize`. Первый лишь выделяет память, но не дает к ней доступа. И следственно `size()` выдаст нули.

Comment: Ну и правильно, я это и имел ввиду.